# I can't find any reference to the UWP Xbox Font

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, xbox-one

I'm working on my first UWP app for Xbox One. I would like to display icons for the Buttons on the Xbox One controller (A,B,X,Y,RB,LB, etc...).

Microsoft uses the **Segoe Xbox MDL2 Symbol** font on Xbox, but I cannot find any documentation for this font. Does anyone know the Unicode values for each button ?

I know that

```
&#xE3CB;
```

displays the X button on the UI, but I need the rest of the buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Massimo Cacchiotti, I have found the similar issue about  [**Segoe Xbox MDL2 Symbol**](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/5e43c61a-34f5-49f8-bf44-e96839cf7932/segoe-xbox-mdl2-symbol?forum=wpdevelop) in msdn. And **Stu** has given [acceptable answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/5e43c61a-34f5-49f8-bf44-e96839cf7932/segoe-xbox-mdl2-symbol?forum=wpdevelop) that you could refer to. The following is answer reference.

> I found that the standard Segoe MDL2 Symbol font on my Creators Update Windows 10 PC had been upgraded from the version that was installed when it was on the Anniversary Edition and now includes all the extra values included from the Xbox version.
>   See if this helps you:
>   [image]

Comment: That's great!  Thanks for the info.